# Proper syntax when SUM case when statement is formatted

Tags: sql-server, sum, case-when

I am trying to sum two different values in my database.

`Species` can either be 12 or 14. I have removed the rest in my select statement.

I want to do a total or `SUM` for all rows that have a species value of 12, and the same when the species has a value of 14.

I don't understand how to format the syntax. This is my query:

```
SELECT h.HarvestDate, c.LotNo, h.Producer, c.species
    SUM CASE WHEN c.Species = 12 THEN LambYT ELSE 0 as LambYT
    SUM CASE WHEN c.Species = 14 THEN LambYTSpoolJoint ELSE 0 as LambYTSpoolJoint
FROM BANSS.dbo.DixonCarcass_InProcess c, BANSS.dbo.HarvestData_SFDCApp h
WHERE c.LotNo = h.Lot
    AND c.Species in (12, 14)
    AND h.Program not LIKE 'K&R%'
GROUP BY h.HarvestDate, c.LotNo, h.Producer
```

However I believe this is incorrect. I would like a `SUM` where `Species = 12` and a sum where `Species = 14` and a total of the two sums as `TOTAL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT h.HarvestDate,
       c.LotNo,
       h.Producer,
      SUM(CASE WHEN c.Species = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LambYT,
      SUM(CASE WHEN c.species = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LambYTSpoolJoint,
      SUM(CASE WHEN c.Species = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE WHEN c.species = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL
FROM BANSS.dbo.DixonCarcass_InProcess c
INNER JOIN BANSS.dbo.HarvestData_SFDCApp h
    ON c.LotNo = h.Lot
WHERE c.Species IN (12, 14) AND
      h.Program NOT LIKE 'K&R%'
GROUP BY h.HarvestDate, c.LotNo, h.Producer
```

**Notes:**

There is no way to do a single aggregation to get your total, because the columns being summed are different for species 12 and 14.  So, I just added the respective `CASE` expressions together.

You can't select `c.species` because it does not appear in your `SELECT` list and it is not inside an aggregate function.

I replaced your implicit join with an explicit one, where the join condition appears in an `ON` clause.  This is the accepted standard now, and it makes it easier to read your query.

Comment: It may be a good idea to include c.species to the selected columns list, and also include it in the grouping

Comment: There is an error on '+', I don't think it understands the math to add both 12 and 14 together.

Comment: @SualehFatehi This crossed my mind, but since he was aggregating over the `species` column I assumed that he didn't want to group by it.  Otherwise the aggregation would make no sense.

Comment: @JoeResler Sorry I had a slight typo in there.  Please try it again.

Comment: it is throwing errors on 'LambYT' being an invalid column name. Same for LambYTSpoolJoint. This is for lines 4, 5, 6, 7. In the case when statements.

Comment: @JoeResler What are you trying to sum here?  Do you want to simply _count_ records, or actually sum a certain column?

Comment: I do not want to count records. I want to sum a column. I found that by changing SUM(CASE WHEN c.species = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS LambYT it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on exactly what you want, but try this:

```
SELECT 
    h.HarvestDate, 
    c.LotNo, 
    h.Producer, 
    c.species,
    SUM(LambYT) AS LambYT,
    SUM(LambYTSpoolJoint) AS LambYTSpoolJoint
FROM 
    BANSS.dbo.DixonCarcass_InProcess c, 
    BANSS.dbo.HarvestData_SFDCApp h
WHERE 
    c.LotNo = h.Lot
    AND c.Species IN (12, 14)
    AND h.Program NOT LIKE 'K&R%'   
GROUP BY 
    h.HarvestDate, 
    c.LotNo, 
    h.Producer,
    c.species
```

or, as Tim B. suggests, try:

```
SELECT 
    h.HarvestDate, 
    c.LotNo, 
    h.Producer, 
    c.species,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.Species = 12 THEN LambYT ELSE 0 END) AS LambYT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.species = 14 THEN LambYTSpoolJoint ELSE 0 END) AS LambYTSpoolJoint
FROM 
    BANSS.dbo.DixonCarcass_InProcess c, 
    BANSS.dbo.HarvestData_SFDCApp h
WHERE 
    c.LotNo = h.Lot
    AND c.Species IN (12, 14)
    AND h.Program NOT LIKE 'K&R%'   
GROUP BY 
    h.HarvestDate, 
    c.LotNo, 
    h.Producer,
    c.species
```

or, better still,

```
SELECT 
    h.HarvestDate, 
    c.LotNo, 
    h.Producer, 
    c.species,
    CASE WHEN c.Species = 12 THEN SUM(LambYT) ELSE SUM(LambYTSpoolJoint) END AS LambYT
FROM 
    BANSS.dbo.DixonCarcass_InProcess c, 
    BANSS.dbo.HarvestData_SFDCApp h
WHERE 
    c.LotNo = h.Lot
    AND c.Species IN (12, 14)
    AND h.Program NOT LIKE 'K&R%'   
GROUP BY 
    h.HarvestDate, 
    c.LotNo, 
    h.Producer,
    c.species
```

Comment: This might not give the intended results because the query sums over _all_ records for species 12 and 14, for both sums.

Comment: That is very close. Although not exactly what I need. The two SUM statements for LambYT and LambYTSpoolJoint don't work. The LambYT is species 12. The LambYTSpoolJoint is 14. So I think I need a case statemetment when species is 12 then sum as LambYT, when species is 14 then sum as LambYTSpoolJoint. Hopefully that clarifies